# How to import one submodule from different submodule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, reference, python-import

My project has the following structure:

```
DSTC/
    st/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        g.py
        tb.py
    dstc.py
```

Here is `a.py` in part:

```
import inspect
import queue
import threading
```

Here is `tb.py` in part:

```
import functools
from . import a
```

When run directly, `a.py` produces no errors, and it is easy to verify there were no `SyntaxError`s. However, running `tb.py` causes the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/DSTC/st/tb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/DSTC/st/tb.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import a
ImportError: cannot import name 'a'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How should I rewrite the import of `a` from `tb` so that `tb` can be run directly without causing errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can use

```
import a
```

or relative

```
from .a import *
```

and in this case module `**a**` should be loaded

```
python -m a tb.py
```

will works for you.

> import * is discouraged, import just as you need

If you got a main.py in your DSTC as follows:

```
#  main.py
from st import tb
```

and you run main.py only relative approach will work for you

```
# tb.py 
import a  # will not work
from .a import * # will work
```

because this time you load 'a' as a module.

Answer (score -1):

you only require to import only module `a`.

```
import a
```

Comment: Well, it *is* an answer, but made redundant by a later, more elaborate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `import .a` or, better, `import st.a`. These will only work if you are importing `tb` as part of your package (e.g. using `python -m` switch from parent directory) rather than running it like a script.

As others have said, simply`import a` will work. This has to advantage of working regardless of whether `st` is run as a module or script, but it's bad practice and only works on python 2, not python 3.

The same applies to the `from` variants that others have mentioned.